# What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?

Tags: discussion

I seen my reputation log a line, which says

```
-10     2 hours ago     removed     User was removed
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the help for this site. It has an explanation for this which I will link to

https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed